# How fast is the water level rising?

Tags: calculus, ratio

A pyramid-shaped vat has square cross-section and stands on its tip. The dimensions at the top are $2\text{ m}\times2\text{ m}$,and the depth is $5\text{ m}$. If water is flowing into the vat at $3\text{ m}^3/\text{min}$, how fast is the water level rising when the depth of water (at the deepest point) is $4\text{ m}$? Note: the volume of any “conical” shape (including pyramids) is $(1/3)(\text{height})(\text{area of base})$.

Comment: Use dV/dt and for V come up with an integral for area by discs. Not sure if that helps or not I'm a little rusty.

Comment: why is there no space between words? it is hard to read.

Comment: You do not need the formula for the volume in order to solve this.  (But knowing that it's $(1/3)\times\text{base}\times\text{height}$ is good in other contexts.)  As the local worshipper of simplicity, I hope my answer shows how to do it simply. And I've up-voted abel's answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Jeff : As I've commented elsewhere on this page, evaluating the integral that gives the volume is unnecessary.  To find $(d/dx)\int_0^x u^u\,du$, you do not need to find $\int_0^2 u^u\,du$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

what the in coming water sees at the moment when the depth is $4 m$ has a square surface area of $\left(\frac 85\right)^2.$  looking  at the volume added in time $dt$ and the change in depth $dh$ are related by $$\left(\frac 85\right) ^2\, dh = 3 \, dt $$ giving you $$ \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{75}{64}\text{ m/min}.$$

Comment: @Michael, what did you v=change? was that left and right parens?

Comment: . . . and also \text{} and space between $3$ and $dt$.  You don't need to ask about this: where it says "edited X mins ago", just click on that and see the edit history. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I see: there's also the change from (\frac 8 5) to \left(\frac 8 5\right).  The difference is between the appearance of $\displaystyle(\frac 8 5)$ and that of $\displaystyle\left(\frac 8 5\right)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

When it's $4$ meters deep, the surface area is $\left(\frac 4 5 \right)^2\times 4\text{ m}^2$. So
$$
\left(\left(\frac 4 5 \right)^2\times 4\text{ m}^2\right) \times (\text{ ? } \text{ m per minute}) = 3\text{ m}^3\text{ per minute}.
$$
Divide both sides by something to get
$$
\text{ ? } \text{ m per minute} = \cdots\cdots
$$

Comment: @MelHikari : Are you still alive?